# How to resolve additional configuration file based on profile in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, properties

I have a files structure like this:

```
- main/resources
    - application.yml
    - externalApi.yml
    - application-dev.yml
    - externalApi-dev.yml
 - test/resources
    - application-test.yml
    - externalApi-test.yml
```

Now in ApiWebClient class I want to use this additional file "externalApi.yml" based on active profile. I used `@PropertySource` like this:

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:externalApi-${spring.profiles.active}.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
public class ApiWebClientImpl implements ApiWebClient {
```

and everything looks fine, application starts. The problem starts in the tests:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApplication.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan(basePackages = "com.xyz.testapplication")
@ActiveProfiles(value = "test")
public class ApiWebClientTest {
```

When I ran it with maven (with "test" profile or without it) like this: `mvn clean install -Ptest` I've got error message that says

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.profiles.active' in value "classpath:externalApi-${spring.profiles.active}.yml
```

So I've added it manually (`@ActiveProfiles` somehow does not work):

`@SpringBootTest(classes = AdapterTestApplication.class, properties = "spring.profiles.active=test")`

and this is working properly but I don't want to update all of the spring boot tests with this part `properties = "spring.profiles.active=test"`. What if I will have like 200 tests? How to do it automatically? Why it does not take proper config file when I run it? Maybe there is way to get rid off `${spring.profiles.active}` in annotation?

Comment: The problem is you are working around/against Spring Boot. Instead tell Spring Boot through properties it needs to load `externalApi` properties as well. Spring Boot will then handle the profile specific bits. For this add `spring.config.name` as a property. It should contain both `application` and `externalApi` like so `spring.config.name=application,externalApi` and now Spring Boot will automatically load both files (including the context specific ones). You can remove the `@PropertySource` now.

Comment: To add Maven Profiles are a different thing then Spring Profiles, so adding `-Ptest` won't activate the Spring Test Profile. Although they share terminology they are totally different things.